# Using a list of stop-words, and then printing the word that triggered it

Tags: string, list, python-2.7

I want to search the input for a list of words. So far this works.

```
swearWords = ["mittens", "boob"]
phrase = raw_input('> ')
listowords = [x.upper() for x in swearWords]
if any(word in phrase.upper() for word in listowords):
   print 'Found swear word!'
else:
   return
```

Now let's say I want to print what the word that was found was?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it (iterate over undesired words, checking whether it's present):

```
undesired_words = ['blah', 'bleh']
user_input = raw_input('> ')

for word in undesired_words:
    if word in user_input.lower():
        print 'Found undesired word:', word

print 'User input was OK.'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code a bit with some comments, check it out:

```
swearWords = ["mittens", "boob"]
phrase = raw_input('> ')

# Here I've split the phrase into words so we can iterate through
phrase_words = phrase.split(' ')

# Now we iterate through both the words and the swear words and see if they match
for word in phrase_words:
    for swear in swearWords:
        if word.upper() == swear.upper():
            print "Found swear word:", swear
```

Here's what I get when I run it:

```
C:\Users\John\Desktop>temp.py
> These are some swear words. Like boob or mittens maybe. Are those really swear
 words?
Found swear word: boob
Found swear word: mittens
```

Hope this helped!